# DownloadManager.addCompletedDownload() deprecated on Android Q

Tags: android, android-download-manager

On upgrading recently to API 29, my code:

```
downloadManager.addCompletedDownload(downloadFilename,
    downloadFilename, true, saveInfo.mimeType,
    downloadPath, outputFile.length(), true)
```

…now produces a deprecation warning:

> Warning: 'addCompletedDownload(String!, String!, Boolean, String!,
>   String!, Long, Boolean): Long' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

The API documentation for DownloadManager.addCompletedDownload says:

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
>   Apps should instead contribute files to MediaStore.Downloads collection to make them available to user as part of Downloads.

However, I have been unable to find a code example of how exactly MediaStore.Downloads should be used as a replacement.  The [MediaStore.Downloads](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Downloads.html) documentation is basically non-existent, and the [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) documentation provides no obvious guidance.

Can anyone provide an API 29-compliant replacement for the above code?

Comment: I would assume you use `MediaStore.Downloads` along the same lines as how you use `MediaStore.Videos`: `insert()` the metadata, then use the `Uri` to write out the file. [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.5/ConferenceVideos) does that for video content.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**

In Android 10 (Q), you must use the `MediaStore` concept.
I did some tests and it seems that downloaded files using Download Manager (and stored at default "Download" folder) are automatically added to `MediaStore.Downloads` database. So, you don't need to manually add them as I described below. For any case, below there's a piece of code where you can insert data into `MediaStore.Downloads`

**Original Answer**

You must update the `MediaStore.Downloads` collection. This way, your file will be visible in the `Downloads` folder. In Android Q, you no longer need to update `DownloadManager` but the `MediaStore.Downloads` collection.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    // You can add more columns.. Complete list of columns can be found at 
    // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Downloads
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.TITLE, /* FILE_NAME */);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, /* DISPLAY NAME */);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE, /* MIME TYPE */);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.SIZE, /* FILE SIZE */);

    // If you downloaded to a specific folder inside "Downloads" folder
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + File.separator + "Temp");

    // Insert into the database
    ContentResolver database = getContentResolver();
    database.insert(Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
} else {
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    if (downloadManager != null) {
        downloadManager.addCompletedDownload(downloadFilename, downloadFilename, true, 
                                  saveInfo.mimeType, downloadPath, outputFile.length(), true)
    }
}
```

**NOTE following differences**

Take this is with a grain of salt since I'm also still checking below points:

1 - Notification is no longer displayed. I guess you are now responsible to notify the user now.

2 - `MediaStore.Downloads` collection accepts files under the "/Downloads" folder only. So, this can affect the download location.

To confirm where inserted etc, you can dump the database as follows:

```
public void dumpDb() {
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    if (downloadManager != null) {
        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query());
        Log.e("TESTS", "DownloadManager dump start");
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.e("TESTS", "Title: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE))
                    + " status: " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))
                    + " id: " + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)));
        }
        Log.e("TESTS", "DownloadManager dump end");
        cursor.close();
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        if (contentResolver != null) {
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null);
            Log.e("TESTS", "MediaStore Collection Dump start");
            if (cursor != null) {
                Log.e("TESTS", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
                cursor.close();
            }

            Log.e("TESTS", "MediaStore Collection Dump end");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Point 1. Notification is no longer displayed => You may call a broadcast like `context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerFinished, uri));`

Comment: bad solution :/ insert method not working. no access to direct path. `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + File.separator + "Temp"` incorrect.