# DownloadManager addCompletedDownload not work on some devices

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager

I have downloaded `File` from my web service, the `File` stored in

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath();
```

Then I use `DownloadManager` to add this file to global `Downloads` folder

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        if (dm != null) {
            dm.addCompletedDownload(
                    file.getName(),
                    file.getName(),
                    true,
                    MIME_TYPE_APPLICATION_PDF,
                    file.getAbsolutePath(),
                    file.length(),
                    true);
        }
```

On some devices it work, on some devices the notification not shown and the file not added to `Downloads` folder (the file successfully downloaded and exists).

**NOTE: all devices < Android 10**

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399849/downloadmanager-addcompleteddownload-deprecated-on-android-q

Comment: For Android 10 i have case and it work fine, I have mentioned that the devices with issue below Android 10